# Where should I 'source'?

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and have been trying to understand how to start building packages and am not able to understand the exact purpose of 'source.' I understand that to test a package I am working on, I should 'source' the setup.* file within the devel file in my workspace.

What exactly is the difference between the source file in the devel space, the install space, or sourcing my environment with "/opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh" ...when would I use one over the other?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66267/where-should-i-%27source%27?/) by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` file adds the packages in the directory `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks` directory (installed from binaries), while the `devel/setup.bash` ads the files in the `src` directory of your catkin build environment. It is OK to source both at once; however, you should only need to source the `devel/setup.bash` file if you are doing work in the catkin workspace. Hope this was of use to you!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2